# Google Map crash null LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps

So I have my google maps, and what I do is get the latitude and longitude from my server as a string then I convert them to a LatLng location. The problem I am having is if the phone doesn't pick up the gps location it stores a empty string in my database and then when the google maps trys to display it, it crashes my app for all users trying to access the map. Which I am gathering is from the empty string, cause if i delete that one from my database everything works fine again. What I need to know is the best way to check from empty string or null LatLng and skip over it so it won't crash.

EDIT CODE UPDATED

```
for (int i = 0; i < marker_list.size(); i+=2)
{
              String lat = marker_list.get(i);
              String lng = marker_list.get(i+1);

              // NEED TO MAKE SURE CHECK BEFORE HERE AND IF LOCATION DOESN'T EXIST SKIP TO NEXT.
              if (lat == "" || lng == "")
              {
                  continue;
              }
              else
{
              double lat_ = Double.valueOf(lat);
          double lng_ = Double.valueOf(lng);

              LatLng location = new LatLng(lat_, lng_);

              map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(location)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(index)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.event)));
 }

}


01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919): Process: com.databasedemo, PID: 919
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.databasedemo.Map$PrefetchData.onPostExecute(Map.java:257)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.databasedemo.Map$PrefetchData.onPostExecute(Map.java:1)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-28 00:33:58.060: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error. Do you get `String lat` and `String lng` null ?

Comment: If you are trying to check that the String has the value "null", use if ("null".equals(lat) && "null".equals(lng)) instead

Comment: Still the same error using if ("null".equals(lat) && "null".equals(lng))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
     String lat = marker_list.get(i);
     String lng = marker_list.get(i+1);
     if(!lat.isEmpty() && !lng.isEmpty())
     {
        try{
         double lat_ = Double.parseDouble(lat);
         double lng_ = Double.parseDouble(lng);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){}
       }
```

Comment: It won't save. Says lat_, lng_ cannot be resolved to a variable on this line. LatLng location = new LatLng(lat_, lng_);

Comment: There's no point in a try catch here. Even if the exception is caught, the values are still wrong.

Comment: Check for the null values of string. Check my updated answer. Do you get the `lat lng` values even ?

Comment: I used if(lat.isEmpty() && lng.isEmpty()){ continue; } and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after you declare your strings.

```
if (lat == "" || lng == "") {
   continue;
}
```

This will skip the iteration where you have empty strings which are giving you null locations

Comment: lat == "" || lng == "" and lat.equals("") || lng.equals("") -- neither of these work and still crashes app.

Comment: @user3186578 Without error message you will no get proper solution so please post the error which you are getting.

Comment: Try changing "" to null. I think the string is null, not empty. So say if (lat == null || lng == null)

Comment: added logcat. I know it's with the double, just unsure how to check for it.. have also tried lat lng == null and still same. Do I need to check double instead for null?

Comment: @user3186578 Whats happening is, your strings are empty. So when you create your double from the string, it gives you an error because the string does not contain a number. I dont see why you are still getting this error even when you follow my answer. Are you sure you put the if statement in my answer BEFORE the declarations of the doubles?

Comment: Please see my updated code, that is what it looks like now. So I am still unsure as well.

Comment: Add a `System.out.println(lat + " " + lng)` before the if statement to see what they are before the crash once and for all

Comment: 01-28 00:54:34.509: I/System.out(1724): Just returns blank.

Comment: @user3186578 Try out with my answer.

Comment: @Grlshu It gives same thing. Blank.

Comment: @user3186578 Ok that means the strings are null, not empty. In that case, change the "" to null and can you put a System.out.println("check") statement inside the if statement to see if it's being executed. It should be

Comment: No it is not being executed.

Comment: I got it by using if(lat.isEmpty() && lng.isEmpty()) { continue; }

Comment: @user3186578 Shouldnt you use || instead of &&? Because even if at least one of them is empty you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the information you're pulling from the database can't be formatted as a number.  You can get this to work but it seems to me the best solution would be to not store corrupt or invalid values in your database.  So just wait for the device to get a position update before pushing something to the database or don't put anything at all.  Also, why are you storing the location as a string? You can push it in as a number so you don't need to serialize and deserialize it every time.

Comment: It's my first android app, I normally do php/mysql so I make it work to as I need. And it's not me storing the locations, I let the users store the locations and if they click the add location button before gps has total lock, it inserts blank values.